# Firefox 38.0.1 : ssl_error_renegotiation_not-allowed

Tags: firefox, ssl-certificate

I cannot access a website even my certificate is valid. Since I got the Firefox update 38.0.1 I get the error code: ssl_error_renegotiation_not_allowed. In the about:config I cannot find it. What can I do? Thanks for helping me. rgds Karin

Comment: Useful reading to understand why you get this message: [SSL and TLS renegotiation vulnerability](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-ssl-and-tls-renegotiation-vulnerability-discovered.html).

Comment: Oh, since it is an SSL (and not a Firefox issue) there is likely no button for it in Firefox.

Comment: Here is Firefox specific info, however I don't know which of the options are still valid in current FF version - https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security:Renegotiation

Comment: The error is not because of SSL certificate, but because the remote server uses an older and vulnerable SSL library version, which does not support secure renegotiation.

Answer (score -1):

Firefox 38 has removed the option to reenable insecure renegotiation. See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1123020

The best solution is to ask the server admin to patch their servers.

Comment: Can you cite a source for this?